# Lookup function for Synchronized DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, landing-page

Good day, friends!
I need to use Lookup function in my Landing page and get data from synchronized DE.
But when I tried to do like this

```
%%[
SET @firstName = Lookup("ENT.Contact_Salesforce","FirstName","Id","0033N00000aiKjiQAE") 
]%%
```

It didn't work. What can be the reason that function couldn't find that DE?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can always troubleshoot your AMPscript in either email when you are previewing it or wrap the code with `try-catch` SSJS block and put error text into the Data Extension. Read more [here](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/09/debugging-ampscript/).

Your script is correct from a syntax point of view (as long as you are filtering by correct ID value and the field names are correct), however, in [February 2019](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/action-required-update-your-data-extension-sharing-model-sapir/?articleId=6612717911750561793) SF changed the way how we can use `.ENT` prefix to access Data Extensions in the Parent BU due to the security reasons. After that for some time it was [possible to also use prefix with Synced DEs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262176/can-we-fetch-data-from-synchronized-data-extension-using-ampscript) but it seems it was a bug and now you can [only use it to access Shared Data Extensions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320283&type=1&mode=1).

If you would run your script in the email, you would recieve this error -
`Access to a Data Extension was denied`, thus it finds the Data Extension from the lookup function but cannot access it.

As a suggestion, you can copy your Synced DE (unfortunately only manually recreate the DE's structure or use the script), transfer all the data via Automation Studio into the copied DE and move it to the Shared DE folder and then run the script again or try to implement your CloudPage and other related assets in the Parent BU.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have copied synchronized DE into the Shared DE and it works now. That was the reason.